# Is univalence equivalent to every type function being a functor over equivalence?

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, functoriality

Introduce a rule in type theory that if $\Gamma \vdash f : \text{Type} \to \text{Type}$ and $\Gamma \vdash e : A \simeq B$ then $\Gamma \vdash f[e] : f(A) \simeq f(B)$.

It may seem like such a rule is redundant (of course type equivalence is preserved by operations on types), but that is not so. Assuming this axiom, $A \simeq B$ implies $A = B$ (because then $A = B$ is equivalent to $B = B$).

This is an interesting alternative to univalence because the axiom doesn't actually refer to type equality. (In a theory without type equality, it still implies that equivalent types satisfy all reflexive relations on types, and gives a way to transport arbitrary structures on equivalent types.)

My question is if this axiom is in fact *equivalent* to the [univalence axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory#The_univalence_axiom).

I'm guessing that the following properties might also need to be assumed, but I'm not sure:

$$id_\text{Type}[e] = e$$
$$(f \circ g)[e] = f[g[e]]$$
$$f[id_A] = id_{f(A)}$$
$$f[e \circ d] = f[e] \circ f[d]$$

Comment: Does the formulation of Univalence as saying that type equivalence is an Identity system already meet your criteria of not referring to type equality?

Comment: @MaxNew yes, that would as well. If this axiom is equivalent to univalence (assuming type equality exists), it will be equivalent to "type equivalence is an identity system" (without assuming type equality).

Comment: What is $f[e]$, a primitive type former? What is the corresponding elimination rule?

Comment: There's a related result in a paper by Steve Awodey at https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/preprints/uapl.pdf where he showed a weak form of univalence is equivalent to a "principle of invariance."

Comment: Can you show the derivation?

Answer (score 7):

Your axiom does not entail univalence.

It is consistent to add to type theory the **isomorphism reflection** rule
$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash e : A \simeq B}{\Gamma \vdash A \equiv B}$$
which states that equivalent types are equal. A model validating this axiom is the *cardinal model* of type theory (see slide 24 [of these slides](https://math.andrej.com/asset/data/TYPES2023-Isomoprhism-invariance-and-reflection.pdf)). Isomorphism reflection entails UIP and is therefore inconsistent with Univalence.

We may interpret your axiom in the presence of isomorphism reflection by setting $f[e] \mathrel{{:}{=}} \mathrm{id}_{f(A)}$ where $f : \mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{U}$ is an endomap on a universe and $e : A \simeq B$. Indeed, from $e : A \simeq B$ and isomorphism reflection we get $A \equiv B$, therefore $f(A) \equiv f(B)$ and $f[e] = \mathrm{id}_{f(A)} : f(A) \simeq f(B)$.

Also, $f[e] = \mathrm{id}_A$ satisfies all the equations you proposed, except $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{U}}[e] = e$ – so I'd have to think about validating that one.